# Background image not changing when scrolling up but works fine while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner at Javascript and Jquery. I am trying to achieve an effect where background image changes on scrolling text. The code works fine for top to bottom scroll but one image is not changing on bottom to top scroll. Here is my code,

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx && scrolledFromtop < 600) // distance to trigger second background image
    {
        $('html').addClass('scrolled');
    }

    else if(scrolledFromtop > 600 && scrolledFromtop < 1000) //  distance to trigger third background image
    {
    $('html').addClass('scrolledtwo');
    }

    else{
        $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('html').removeClass('scrolledtwo')
    }
});
</script>    
<style>

html {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

html {
   background-image:url(assets/images/b1.jpeg);
}

html.scrolled {
    background-image:url(assets/images/ab3.jpeg);
}
html.scrolledtwo {
    background-image:url(assets/images/ab9.jpeg);
}   

</style>
</head>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: remove the other class in your if and elseif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only problem was :
You were not removing the older added class and were adding new class, at in the middle region i.e. > 600 you are having both the classes scrolled and scrolledTwo.

So one solution is :
Remove the older class before adding new class.

Use these lines at correct places :

a- $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
b- $('html').removeClass('scrolledTwo');

use this script :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx && scrolledFromtop < 600) // distance to trigger second background image
{

    $('html').removeClass('scrolledtwo')
    $('html').addClass('scrolled');
}

else if(scrolledFromtop > 600 && scrolledFromtop < 1000) //  distance to trigger third background image
{
$('html').removeClass('scrolled');  
$('html').addClass('scrolledtwo');
}

else{    
    ***$('html').removeClass('scrolled');***
    $('html').removeClass('scrolledtwo')
}
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must try it like this, the `classes` which were added during `scroll` could also needs to be removed at certain conditions as below,

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
  var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx && scrolledFromtop <= 600) // distance to trigger second background image
  {
    $('html').addClass('scrolled');
    $('html').removeClass('scrolledtwo');
  } else if (scrolledFromtop >= 601 && scrolledFromtop < 1000) //  distance to trigger third background image
  {
    $('html').addClass('scrolledtwo');
    $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $('html').removeClass('scrolled');
    $('html').removeClass('scrolledtwo')
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  height: 1200px;
}

html {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150/111/fff");
}

html.scrolled {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150/f11/fff");
}

html.scrolledtwo {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150/f2f/fff");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove `.scrolledtwo` class when `scrollTop` is between 200 to 600, same-way remove `.scrolled` when it between 601 to 1000 else if it crosses the condition remove both.

Comment: @Riya Jain in-between it skips the adding and removal of classes, so you need to remove them in if condition, else part plays after it crosses the scrollTop of 1000.

Comment: Oh yes! What a mistake. Thank you so much for the help. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Welcome @RiyaJain :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.
Have a look.
Make a long page you will see the effect.
You have set the criteria to change the background image.

Good work.